# My whole parsing logic suffers because of null character how to resolve this

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, parsing, visual-c++

This is DATA 1

```
RE00002200050046\00 0.00 0.1 0.125.9\0#####-  14    0##### \0   0#####   141.0\004.00 0: 00.000.0\00 4: 011:27 0: 015:27#\0###########2.00.0\0
```

Another data that i have is 
This is DATA 2

```
RE000022601\0500460 0.00 0.1\0 0.236.8####\0#   57-   2#####-   3#####\0-  601.004.0\00 4: 00.000.\000 4: 013:37 0\0: 017:37#####\0#######2.00.\00
```

The above data is the response i get from an hospital machine,i have to parse the above values and fill it according to given format:-

```
BYTEs  2         2         4             128            2         2
   +---------+--------+------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
   |  RE     |  00    |  machine no|   Data part     |  Check | CRC   |
   |         |        |            |                 |   sum  |       |
   +---------+--------+------------+-----------------+--------+-------+
```

As you can see from DATA 1 My data part begins from "000500.."
and DATA 2 My data part begins from "601\0500..."
While doing parsing i got into a problem that there is field named "Blood pump flow" whose length is 3 bytes from the "DATA 1" we get its value as "46" while from the 
"DATA 2" i got its value as "460".
In actual its value should be "460"
If i get a data like DATA 1 my whole parsing logic suffers as because as "Blood pump flow" is "3 bytes" i get a value "46\0" and **"0"** **is added to another field while "Blood pump flow" should be "460".**
The above is just one case i get it many times for some other fields too.
How to resolve this problem.

DATA 1 and DATA 2 are the binary data that i get from the machine.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your explanation.

Comment: Please show the code, it is easier to understand that way.

Comment: QJesse Good the parsing code?

Comment: Yes. We cannot see the parsing logic.

Comment: Publish the code you're using to parse.

Comment: Is this binary or text format. Two different approaches are for them. Presence of `'\0'` suggests this is binary format. Do you know length of fields in your records?

Comment: @PiotrNycz ya i know the length of each field

Comment: @user1402643 I mean your input field sizes - not output.

Comment: @JesseGood Sir you can see the code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/my-whole-parsing-logic-suffers-because-of-null-character-how-to-resolve-this

Comment: @PiotrNycz ya i know each field size,i mean they have given the description that this field will be of this much byte and so on..

Comment: @PiotrNycz i updated the info i have in my ques

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster you can have a look at the code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/my-whole-parsing-logic-suffers-because-of-null-character-how-to-resolve-this

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your example, and it is confirmed by your own comment, that you know the field sizes in your format. So you must treat this input as binary input. Use `std::istream::read` function.

```
unsigned char header[14];
is.read(header,14);
if (is.gcount() == 14)
{
    // decide which DATA1 or DATA2 you read from header contents
    if (header is for DATA1)
      // read rest of input as DATA1
    // decide which DATA1 or DATA2 you read from header contents
    else if (header is for DATA2)
      // read rest of input as DATA2
    else
      //report error
}
```

Comment: Sir i have not to decide which DATA 1 or DATA 2 is to be used,DATA 1 and DATA 2 are the binary data that i get when i request the machine,i request the machine regarding data periodically after a minute so sometimes in response i get DATA 1 and some time in response i get DATA 2.

Comment: So you need to check if header read from response is for DATA1 or DATA2 - then read the rest of binary data respectively as DATA1 or DATA2.